# Are there any photosynthetic catalysts in use other than chlorophyll?

Tags: photosynthesis, biodiversity

When I search for catalysts other than chlorophyll on Google, I only get references to artificial photosynthesis. When I look up photosynthesis, I see accessory pigments mentioned, but it appears that the chlorophyll family is crucial.

These chlorophyll variants all have the [chlorin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorin) (not to be confused with chlorine) ring in common.

Are there any photosynthetic organisms that do not use a chlorin derivative? Why is chlorin so predominant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are photosynthetic organisms that use retinal-rhodopsin complex. However, the mechanism of photosynthesis is different in these organisms than those that employ chlorophyll dependent photosystems. In these organisms, the light causes the rhodopsin-like membrane proteins to pump proton out of the cell and create a proton gradient which in turn is used by the ATP synthase to make ATP.

See this post too [Why are there no known photosynthetic archaea?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/30308/3340)

This mechanism of "photosynthesis" is not as efficient as the chlorophyll dependent one (page 22, Baltscheffsky, 1997<sup>†</sup>). Moreover, it does not produce NADPH.

---

<sup>†</sup> Baltscheffsky, Herrick. *[Origin and evolution of biological energy conversion](http://as.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471185817.html)*. New York etc: VCH, 1996. Print. ISBN: 978-0-471-18581-9

Comment: What is the efficiency of that process, compared to chlorophyll photosynthesis?

Comment: I think you would do better to ask that as a separate question, rather than commenting on a four-year old answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would say even [photolyase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photolyase) counts since it uses light to change chemical bonds in DNA repair.